# Toolbar height from top for all android verison

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

i want to show one ui below toolbar but problem is say my toolbar size is 50dp and if i say my layout margin from top 50 then for some android version its working  . i think above api 22 we also need status_bar_height which includes in toollbar height .
what is the best way to get toolbar height so that i can show view above that toolbar . i am showing one overlay screen with transparent

```
 int statusBar = getStatusBarHeight();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, (statusBar + 50), 0, 0);
                MainRel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                MainRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


 public int getStatusBarHeight() {
     int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this generic code. Override the `OnWindowFocusChanged`

```
  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      int toolbarHeight = toolbar.getHeight();
      int statusBar = getStatusBarHeight();
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       layoutParams.setMargins(0, (statusBar + toolbarHeight), 0, 0);//you can use the toolbar height you got here. 
       MainRel.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
       MainRel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
  }
```

Comment: but statusBar only needed after api 22